# JSON HTTP response - get a single integer

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display a single digit integer (0 and 1) coming as an HTTP response. I'm not sure how to get that integer and store it? What function should I use?

```
    http_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
            if (http_request.status == 200) {
                // ...what goes here?...
            }
            setTimeout("loadJSON()", 1000);
        }
    }

    http_request.open("GET", data_file, true);
    http_request.send();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response of AJAX calls like that is accessible from the `responseText` property:

```
if (http_request.status == 200) {
    doStuffWith(http_request.responseText);
}
```